# Android and iot Hub Azure , create service mqtt client

Tags: android, azure, mqtt, background-service, azure-iot-hub

I read and follow what are in this link : 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/tree/master/device/iot-device-samples/android-sample

Now , because i want that my app run in background and listen messages received from the iothub Azure , i create a Service.
This service have a timer task to send after n-time a report to my server.
This service open connection with the azureiot sdk and wait for message.

I know is a bad solution , and i see that sometimes don't catch the message or catch it with an annoying delay.

What is the right implementation of this kind of client mqtt listener on a service ( or not if is wrong ) on android app that run in background ?

This is my code :

```
public class HomeService extends Service {
    public static final long INTERVAL = 15 * 1000;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Timer mTimer = null;
    private RequestQueue queue;
    private CommandSender commandSender;
    DeviceClient client = null;

    private boolean statelight = false;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unsupported Operation");
    }

    ///private final static String CONN_STRING = "HostName=LifeSensorHub.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=device;SharedAccessKey=MhPmT3Hl4JMEbiNI/xpd+YO7AfWEGUuMXQUzbNF/+PA=;DeviceId=android-tv-dev";

    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                waitForMessage();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        new Thread(runnable).start();

        if (mTimer != null)
            mTimer.cancel();
        else
            mTimer = new Timer();
        commandSender = new CommandSender(this);
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, INTERVAL);
    }

    public void waitForMessage() {
        IotHubClientProtocol protocol = IotHubClientProtocol.MQTT;
        try {
            if(client == null) {
                client = new DeviceClient(AzureHelper.CONN_STRING, protocol);
            }
                try {
                    client.open();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    System.out.println("Exception while opening IoTHub connection: " + e1.toString());
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    System.out.println("Exception while opening IoTHub connection: " + e2.toString());
                }

            if (protocol == IotHubClientProtocol.MQTT) {
                AzureHelper.MessageCallbackMqtt callback = new AzureHelper.MessageCallbackMqtt(commandSender);
                AzureHelper.Counter counter = new AzureHelper.Counter(0);
                client.setMessageCallback(callback, counter);
            } else {
                AzureHelper.MessageCallback callback = new AzureHelper.MessageCallback();
                AzureHelper.Counter counter = new AzureHelper.Counter(0);
                client.setMessageCallback(callback, counter);
            }

            Thread.sleep(2000);
            client.close();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mTimer.cancel();
    }

    private class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    makeRequest();
                }
            });
        }
    }


    private void makeRequest() {
        commandSender.getStatus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe Notification Hub is helpful. You can check [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/event-hubs-dotnet-user-notifications/).